# Flutter how to fix error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error when I am trying to run my flutter app:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/user/Developer/newapp/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:119: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.user.newapp:string/app_name) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it? I have tried to clean and run the project but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

Add file `strings.xml` to the path `/android/app/src/main/res/values/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">your_app_name</string>
</resources>
```

Hope to help you